# How to compare the substring of inputs in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("select case when type = 'KEY' then case when length(key)>0 and key not rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' then '' else case when key rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' then regexp_extract(key, '^[^@]+', 0) else '' end end else '' end as id from input").show(false)


`Seq(("KEY","123451ad2cd@gmail.com","1ad2cd@gmail.com")).toDF("type","key","email")`
```

I've given the input data and the query here.

The query which I have written is for two input and need to be updated with the following rules.

- When type = 'key' and key>0 then should process further, if not then nullify
- When type = 'key' and key>0 then we need to extract ID from key column which holds both ID and email.
- For extracting we need to compare the email and key column and eliminate the email , what remains is the ID.((i.e) key - email = ID)
- The extracted ID should not contain anything other than numbers.

Sample Input Dataframe:

```
+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
|type |key                      |email           |
+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
|KEY  |123451ad2cd@gmail.com    |1ad2cd@gmail.com|
|KEY  |123abcd451ad2cd@gmail.com|1ad2cd@gmail.com|
|DELTA|123451ad2cd@gmail.com    |1ad2cd@gmail.com|
+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Required Output:

```
+------+
|id    |
+------+
|12345 |
|      |
|      |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following SQL query should work for you.

First will replace email with `''` in key column then check if remaining value contains only digits. If it contains only digits will extract those.

```
  spark.sql(
    """
      |SELECT
      |     CASE WHEN type = 'KEY' and LENGTH(key) > 0
      |          THEN
      |            CASE WHEN regexp_replace(key, email, '') rlike '^\\d+$'
      |                 THEN regexp_replace(key, email, '')
      |                 ELSE ''
      |            END
      |         ELSE ''
      |     END AS id FROM input
      |""".stripMargin).show(false)
```

Comment: The query works fine but when if the number is there in email it also comes with the ID. It should not come like that. For example if the input for key is : 123451ad2cd@gmail.com                and email: 1ad2cd@gmail.com then the output should be: 12345. You query is giving output as 123451.(email should be completely eliminated whether it is alphabet or number) can you please correct this!  @Mohana B C

Comment: By mistake, added extarct instead replace. You can check now.

Comment: can you please provide the statement which runs without triple quotes and strip margin.?

Comment: Put complete query in single line and enclose it with double quotes.

Comment: can you please correct this query.....spark.sql("select case when length(medicare)>0 then lpad(right(medicare,13),13,' ') else '' end as medicare from input").show(false)
In the above query if the input is  if the input is 12345678901234567 then I'm getting output as 5678901234567 but the expected output is FIRST 13 characters 1234567890123...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use dataframe API directly and achieve this using when otherwise.

Basically what i have done is that i am checking if the type, email and key are not null, length of key is greater than 0 simply replace any occurrence  of the corresponding email in key by empty string else set the new value to null

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val newDf = df.withColumn("new_col", 
                         when($"type".isNotNull && $"type" === "KEY" && $"key".isNotNull && length($"key") > 0 && $"email".isNotNull, regexp_replace($"key", $"email", lit("")))
                          otherwise(null)
                         )

newDf.show(false)
```